# c:when is not being evaluated

Tags: jsp

I have the following form snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label class="pull-left" path="officeName">Office Name ${isInternational}</form:label>
    <form:errors path="officeName" class="error pull-left"></form:errors>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${isInternational}">
        <form:input path="officeName" type="text" class="form-control" id="officeName" placeholder="Enter Office Name"></form:input>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
        <form:input path="officeName" type="text" class="form-control" id="officeName" placeholder="Enter Office Name" readonly="readonly" ></form:input>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

I can always get `Office Name ${isInternational}` to print the appropriate value, but no matter what the form field is enabled.  Thanks.

Edit: `disabled="disabled" also does not work`

Comment: are you using struts-tags or spring-tag support ?

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring consider the tag properties could be different

```
readonly(false/true)

HTML Optional Attribute. Setting the value of this attribute to 'true' (without the quotes) will disable the HTML element.
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input

I mean the values must be true or false, read link above.